# Como pegar uma imagem da tela guardar na pasta do projeto e salvar o caminho no banco Mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, imagem, aplicação-web, jsp

Entao,eu tenho um jsp com formulario,ele converte a imagem para b64 e envia como string pro servlet o servlet converte a b643

```
String stt = request.getParameter("base64img");
        try{
            String parts[] = stt.split(",");
            String imgPart = parts[1];
        BufferedImage image = null;
        byte[] imageByte;
        BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
        imageByte = decoder.decodeBuffer(imgPart);
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByte);
        image = ImageIO.read(bis);
        bis.close();
        // write the image to a file
        File outputfile = new File("image.png");
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", outputfile);

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

E ele grava a imagem na src do projeto,como eu recupero este caminho para inserir no banco??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, use o método getAbsolutePath().

Por exemplo:

```
String diretorio = outputfile.getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: Obrigado!!!!!!!